# MySQL como crear una tabla Recursiva?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estoy usando MySQL Workbench,

```
Socio(idSocio(PK),nombreSocio,telSocio, idSocAvala(FK))//Recursiva
```

Tengo una entidad Socio que tiene una relacion Recursiva, pero nose como crear la tabla recursiva. Alguien sabra como crear una tabla recursiva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una llave foranea no importa que sea dentro de la misma tabla:

```
ALTER TABLE Socio ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_recursiva` FOREIGN KEY (`idSocAvala`) REFERENCES `Socio` (`idSocio`)
```

Suponiendo que tu tabla ya esta creada y se llama socio

Comment: Graciiias =) si si me ayudo